# insert data into a 2d array

Tags: php

suppose I have the follwing matrix data:

```
 2  3  
 4  5 
 6  7
 8  9
```

How to insert them into a 2d php array, can anybody help me with that, I am new to php 2d array, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is this data coming from?

Comment: So the data is actually comma separated?

Comment: [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv) is your friend.

Comment: no,sorry, the data is not from csv, I made the data my self, I want to know how to declare a 2d arrya in php and how to insert data into the 2d array

Comment: At least give us an example of how you want the data to look when it is in the array, there's far too many possible ways to "insert these values" into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually want a 2D array or do you want your first columns to be the keys?

You can do this:

```
$key = 2;
$value = 3;
$array[$key] = $value;
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $array ); echo '</pre>';
// outputs  array( [2] => 3 )
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    echo $key.' - '.$value.' <br />';
}
// outputs: 2 - 3
```

You can also do this:

```
 $array[] = array( '2', '3' );    
 $array[] = array( '4', '5' );    
 // outputs  
      array( [0] => array( 
                     [0] => 2,
                     [1] => 3 )
             [1] => array( 
                     [0] => 4,
                     [1] => 5 )
           )
```

Read this and post back with a more specific question if you are not understanding somewhere.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Also, the reason the comments are asking you where you got the data is because you can automate much of this process.  If you are pulling it from a database, then the 2D arrays can be made automatically.  Otherwise, the process I just did above is very manual.  I don't know think I've ever made an array like this in a production environment.  They are always in for or foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
$My_Array[] = array();
$My_Array[0] = "pos3", "mem1", "Clip Art", "Got some good clip art?", "2006-04-13 12:11:06"
```

OR

Below is with html example

```
/* 2 dimensional array in PHP - strictly an
array of arrays ... setup: */

for ($k=1;$k<=10;$k++) {
for ($j=1;$j<=10;$j++) {
    $multable[$k][$j] = $j/$k;
}
}

# ---------------------------------------------
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>An array of arrays in PHP</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=white>
<h2>Two dimensional array</h2><br>
<table border=2 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2>

<?php

/* Very easy to produce a table from a 2D array! */
for ($k=1;$k<=10;$k++) {
    print "<tr>";
    for ($j=1;$j<=10;$j++) {
        echo "<td>",$multable[$j][$k],"</td>";
        }
    print "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```